# I want to make the following table

Tags: html

[image]    [image]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbDnR.png
```

I haven't tried this but it will use  **tags** and also table. 
I am a noob so i need assistance here .

Comment: okk i try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<hr/>
<table class="finaltable" border="2">
    <tr>
        <td>final</td>
        <td>hii</td>
        <td>hii</td>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="finaltable2" border="2">
    <tr>
        <td>final</td>
        <td>hii</td>
        <td>hii</td>
        <td>hii</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>final</td>
        <td>hii</td>
        <td>hii</td>
        <td>hii</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Only `td` and `th` tags can go inside of a `tr`: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element

Comment: well done you need more practise keep it up

Comment: thanks i will do it

Answer (score 1):

I hope you will find this usefull:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>table demo</title>
<style>
    table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
  <tr align="center">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Telephone</th>
    <th>e-mail</th>
    <th>City</th>
  </tr>
  </table>
<hr>
  <table>
  <tr align="center">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Telephone</th>
    <th>e-mail</th>
    <th>City</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td> 
    <td>8</td>   
  </tr>

</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```